# How to map results within vue computed property

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

Our app has multiple locations, each with an accessGroup of a, b, c, or d.
Our users have an array of accessGroups ['a', 'c'] etc.

On our locations page, myLocations should return the locations where the location.accessGroup is included within their accessGroup array.

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['currentUser', 'locations', 'userProfile']),
}
myLocations: function() {
    return this.locations.filter((location) => {
      return location.accessGroup === this.userProfile.accessGroup
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are comparing a string with array. Try this:

```
// assuming userProfile.accessGroup is an array of strings like ['a', 'c'] etc
// and location.accessGroup is a string: 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd'
myLocations () {
  return this.locations.filter((location) => {
    return this.userProfile.accessGroup.indexOf(location.accessGroup) >= 0
  })
}
```